# CudaAPIError 716 when trying to copy data from gpu

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, numba

I'm learning Numba and CUDA Python. I've been following a set of [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPQnFXD7DxM&index=11&list=PL5B692fm6--vScfBaxgY89IRWFzDt0Khm) and have (I believe) understood the principals. My issue is with copying computed values back from my GPU. I use  the following line to do this:

```
aVals = retVal.copy_to_host()
```

I've also tried using this line:

```
retVal.copy_to_host( aVals[:] )
```

Neither work and both give the same error:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: [716] Call to cuMemcpyDtoH results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR
```

I'm reasonably confident the above lines are the issue as if I comment out the line the code runs without errors. Is there some underlying issue I'm overlooking with copying an array from GPU to CPU? Have I screwed up my arrays somewhere?

There's a lot of messing around in my code but here's a bare bones version:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from math import sin, cos, tan, sqrt, pi, floor

from numba import vectorize, cuda

@cuda.jit('void(double[:],double[:],double[:],double)')
def CalculatePreValues(retVal,ecc, incl,  ke):
    i= cuda.grid(1)

    if i >= ecc.shape[0]:
        return

    retVal[i] = (ke/ecc[i])**(2/3)


def main():
    eccen = np.ones(num_lines, dtype=np.float32)
    inclin = np.ones(num_lines, dtype=np.float32)
    ke = 0.0743669161
    aVals = np.zeros(eccen.shape[0])
    start = time.time()
    retVal = cuda.device_array(aVals.shape[0])

    ecc = cuda.to_device(eccen)
    inc = cuda.to_device(inclin)


    threadsPerBlock = 256
    numBlocks = int((ecc.shape[0]+threadsPerBlock-1)/threadsPerBlock)


    CalculatePreValues[numBlocks, threadsPerBlock](retVal,ecc,inc)

    aVals = retVal.copy_to_host()

    preCalcTime = time.time() - start
    print ("Precalculation took % seconds" % preCalcTime)
    print (aVals.shape[0])

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That kernel won't compile because `ke` isn't defined anywhere. And the error you are seeing will be caused by a runtime error in the kernel, so could you fix it?

Comment: This is an incorrect thread check: `if i > ecc.shape[0]: return`, it should be `if i >= ecc.shape[0]: return`.  numba cuda uses zero-based indexing in this case.  However, you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @talonmies you are right! However I made this mistake in cutting down my code to figure out the issue (and post to here), in my original code I didn't have this error. Upon fixing this error the code still fails with the same error!

Comment: @RobertCrovella the code I use to populate the ecc and incl values is long and based on a number of read files - how best should I deal with posting that to SE? The fix of changing i> ecc... to i>= ecc... hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: The request for a [mcve] isn't a request for **your whole code**. It is a request for a minimal example.  Remove anything that is unnecessary.  Your code should compile and run and show the issue.  But it's unlikely that exactly how you initialize the data in host code will make any difference for this kernel.   For example, just create your arrays with `np.ones()`.  I doubt it will matter. Go read the MCVE link again.  It already answers your question about what to do.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for clearing that up. I've editied the code to be as you suggested. I can confirm the error still occurs.

Comment: Your thread check remains incorrect.  Furthermore your kernel signature specifies `double` for all values, but you are passing `dtype=np.float32` type.  That is a mismatch and will cause problems.

Comment: @RobertCrovella that my friend is why you earn the big bucks (reputation). The problem was the type mismatch! If you could write an answer to that effect I'll mark as accepted! Thanks again

Comment: The currently provided CW answer has been updated to reflect this.  You're welcome to accept that one if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points to make here.

Firstly, the source of the error you are seeing is a runtime error coming from the kernel execution. If I run a hacky "fixed" version of your code using cuda-memcheck, I see this:

```
$ cuda-memcheck python ./error.py 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 8
=========     at 0x00000178 in cudapy::__main__::CalculatePreValues$241(Array<double, int=1, A, mutable, aligned>, Array<double, int=1, A, mutable, aligned>, Array<double, int=1, A, mutable, aligned>)
=========     by thread (255,0,0) in block (482,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7061317f8 is out of bounds
```

The reason is that the bounds checking in your kernel is broken:

```
    if i > ecc.shape[0]:
        return
```

should be

```
    if i >= ecc.shape[0]:
        return
```

When the question was updated to include a MCVE, it became evident that there was another issue.  The kernel signature specifies `double` for all the arrays:

```
@cuda.jit('void(double[:],double[:],double[:],double)')
                ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^
```

but the type of arrays created were actually `float` (i.e. `np.float32`):

```
eccen = np.ones(num_lines, dtype=np.float32)
inclin = np.ones(num_lines, dtype=np.float32)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is a mismatch.  Indexing into an array using `double` indexing, when the array has only been created with `float` values, will likely create out-of-bounds indexing.

The solution is to convert the created arrays to `dtype=np.float64`, or else convert the arrays in the signature to `float`:

```
@cuda.jit('void(float[:],float[:],float[:],double)')
```

to eliminate the out-of-bounds indexing.